# Array of multiple types C# (including other arrays)

Tags: c#, arrays, types

Is there a way to have an array of multiple types in c#, including other arrays?
Apparently I can do this:

```
object[] x = {1,"G",2.3, 2,'H'};
```

but not this:

```
object[] x = {1,"G",2.3, 2,'H', {2} };
```

What's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is that that you cannot initialize the inner array this way. The array initalizer can only be used in a variable or field initializer. As your error states:

> Array initializer can only be used in a variable or field initializer. Try using a new expression insead

You must explicitly initialize the nested arrays. Do it this way and it works:

```
object[] x = { 1, "G", 2.3, 2, 'H', new int[]{ 2 } };
// Or a bit cleaner
object[] x = { 1, "G", 2.3, 2, 'H', new []{ 2 } };
```

Read more on [Array Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx)

Your syntax would work if you'd define a 2 dimensional array:

```
object[,] x = { {"3"}, { 1 }, { 2 } };
```

Answer (score 4):

`object[] x = {1,"G",2.3, 2,'H', {2} };` was wrong and u can use

`object[] x = { 1, "G", 2.3, 2, 'H', new int[]{ 2 } };`